# Декодирование экранированных юникод-символов на C++

Tags: c++, json, unicode

JSON-to-XML парсер на C++ успешно разбирает json объект на составляющие, но этот объект вместо кириллицы содержит закодированные символы типа "\u0410". Надо эти символы преобразовать в нормальные буквы для записи в XML файл.

У меня конечно есть идея - построить `map` символов и проанализировать строку, но может есть какая-то функция для подобной конвертации строки, чтобы не изобретать велосипеды?

Comment: В json как `"А"` так и `"\u0410"` представляют один и тот же символ А (U+0410). Если парсер не понимает \u0410, то это не json парсер.

Comment: В общем, сделал сравнением подстрок со значениями ключей map<string, string>, например, ключ "\\u0410", значение "А" - и так для всего алфавита. Топорно, но работает )

Comment: Json не сложно распознать, но к чему самому писать, если уже много json библиотек для c++, в том числе header-only